# Does Android Geocoder understand street intersections?

Tags: android

The Android Geocoder does not appear to understand intersections like the web-based Google Maps API.  For example, a street intersection, "aviation and bataan", from Google maps returns a valid geopoint:
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=aviation%20and%20battan&sensor=false

Using the Geocoder in Android, this same intersection search ("aviation and bataan") returns no results.  My Android code below **does** returns results when I enter a more specific address instead of an intersection.  Does the Android Geocoder not understand intersections or do I need to do something else?

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this);
        try {
            foundAdresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(query, MAX_SEARCH_RESULTS);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not, you should ignore the faulty incomplete GeoCoder object and just use the online version in a get request

`http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=DESIREDADDRESS&sensor=true`

it returns a JSON object

Answer (score 0):

You can inspect current `GeoCoder.java` on android source tree (here's an [older example](http://android-x86.tarot.com.tw/?p=android-x86/platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=location/java/android/location/Geocoder.java;h=2ce127367a85f17bd1bd6e2f0c45bc047295a689;hb=HEAD)) and decide whether to use GeoCoder class or Map Reverse Geocoding API directly.

I don't know what causes this but it must be about how GeoCoder class queries Reverse Geocoding API. Read GeoCoder source code and try to figure out yourself. That's my advice and if you don't have much time, just move on with Reverse Geocoding API (JSON), Android has a built-in JSON parser library (`gson`).

Comment: Ahmet, I will look into your suggestion.  Thanks.